# ¿Que hace el Request.Form["codproducto"] en asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp

Vi el siguiente codigo en internet:

Request.Form["codproducto"]

pero no se cual es la funcion de Request.Form y el codproducto que representa?,agradeceria su explicacion y su uso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomado de la Mozilla Foundation:

> Los formularios HTML son uno de los puntos principales de interacción entre un usuario y un sitio web o aplicación. Ellos permiten a los usuarios enviar información a un sitio web. La mayor parte de las veces se envía información a un servidor web, pero la pagina web también puede interceptarla para usarla por su lado.
>
> Un formulario HTML está hecho de uno o más widgets. Estos widgets puede ser campos de texto (de una linea o multilínea), cajas de selección, botones, checkboxes, o botones de radio. La mayoría del tiempo, estos widgets están junto a un label que describe su propósito.

Todos los formularios HTML comienzan con el elemento  de la siguiente forma:

```
<form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">

</form>
```

Entonces, basicamente cuando el formulario realiza un post al servidor, todos los inputs que están dentro del `FORM` se envían al servidor en una colección de key `string` value `string`.

Cuando tu ves `Request.Form["codproducto"]` estás viendo como el servidor está tratando de leer un valor que fue posteado bajo el `name` "codproducto". Por ejemplo

```
<form action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
    <input name="codproducto" type="text">
</form>
```