# Pasar valores entre paginas asp con Response.Redirect(URL) y Request.Form

Tags: asp.net, webforms, requests

Les cuento que estoy haciendo un proyecto de tipo Aplicación Web ASP.NET(.NET Framework) solo para realizar algunas pruebas, para esto estoy utilizando VisualStudio 2017.

Dentro del proyecto he creado dos paginas (Formulario Web Forms) con nombre `Inicio.aspx` y `Redirect.aspx`

En la pagina de `inicio.aspx` tengo un textbox (`txtSaludo`) y un botón.
En la pagina `Redirect.aspx` solo tengo dos textbox

Desde el evento clic del botón que esta en inicio.aspx quiero pasar el valor de txtSaludo a la pagina `Redirect.aspx`.

Para hacer esto el código en el evento clic del botón de la pagina `Inicio.aspx` es el siguiente:

```cs
protected void btnRedirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = string.Empty;
    url = string.Format("{0}?nombre={1}","PaginaRedirect.aspx",txtSaludo.Text);
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Ahora en el evento `load()` de la pagina Redirect.aspx quiero recuperar los valores, para esto uso el siguiente codigo:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        string nombre = Request.Params["nombre"];
        if(nombre != null)
        {
            this.txtNombre.Text = nombre;
            this.txtNombreForm.Text = Request.Form["txtSaludo"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Con **`Request.Params`** logro recuperar el valor sin problemas.
Pero con **`Request.Form`** me da el error:

> **System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'**

El código de Inicio.aspx es el siguiente:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSaludo" runat="server">Hola Mundo!</asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnRedirect" runat="server" Text="Llamado por Redirect" OnClick="btnRedirect_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Quizas esta respuesta te ayude: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/145985/1171

Comment: Hola vi el post sugerido, la diferencia es que en los controles (TextBox) de aspx no tengo la propiedad name.  <br />   <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSaludo" runat="server">Hola Mundo!</asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnRedirect" runat="server" Text="Llamado por Redirect" OnClick="btnRedirect_Click" />
        </div>
    </form><br /> Intente ponerlo en duro directamente al codigo pero sale el mismo error, tambien intente agregar la propiedad post en la etiqueta form, y tampoco ha funcionado.